# No Encoder found for org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jts, geomesa

While using Geomesa and Scala, I have been attempting to encode 2 columns in a Spark Dataframe using the below snippets, but I am continually receiving an issue where it appears that Scala cannot serialize the returned objects into a Dataframe.  When using Postgres and PostGIS, life is easy - is this an easy issue, or is there a better library which can handle Geospatial querying coming from a Spark Dataframe that contains latitute and longitude in Double format?

The versions that I am using in my SBT are:

- spark:    2.3.0
- scala:    2.11.12
- geomesa:  2.2.1
- jst-*:    1.17.0-SNAPSHOT

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.{Coordinate, GeometryFactory}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts._


object GetRandomData {


  def main(sysArgs: Array[String]) {

    @transient val spark: SparkSession = {
      SparkSession
        .builder()
        .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false")
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
        .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.mb","24")
        .appName("GetRandomData")
        .master("local[*]")
        .getOrCreate()
    }
    val sc = spark.sparkContext
    sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")
    import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

    var coordinates = sc.parallelize(
      List(
        (35.40466, -80.905458),
        (35.344079, -80.872267),
        (35.139606, -80.840845),
        (35.537786, -80.780051),
        (35.525361, -83.031932),
        (34.928323, -80.766732),
        (35.533865, -82.72344),
        (35.50997,  -80.588572),
        (35.286251, -83.150514),
        (35.558519, -81.067069),
        (35.569311, -80.916993),
        (35.835867, -81.067904),
        (35.221695, -82.662141)
      )
    ).
    toDS().
    toDF("geo_lat", "geo_lng")

    coordinates = coordinates.select(coordinates.columns.map(c => col(c).cast(DoubleType)) : _*)
    coordinates.show()
    val testing = coordinates.map(r => new GeometryFactory().createPoint(new Coordinate(3.4, 5.6)))
    val coordinatesPointDf = coordinates.withColumn("point", st_makePoint(col("geo_lat"), col("geo_lng")))

  }
}
```

The exception is:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: No Encoder found for org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point
- root class: "org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point"
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:643)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor$1.apply(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at scala.reflect.internal.tpe.TypeConstraints$UndoLog.undo(TypeConstraints.scala:56)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:824)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.cleanUpReflectionObjects(ScalaReflection.scala:39)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$ScalaReflection$$serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:445)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.serializerFor(ScalaReflection.scala:434)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder$.apply(ExpressionEncoder.scala:71)
  at org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts.encoders.SpatialEncoders$class.jtsPointEncoder(SpatialEncoders.scala:21)
  at org.locationtech.geomesa.spark.jts.package$.jtsPointEncoder(package.scala:17)
  at GetRandomData$.main(Main.scala:50)
  at GetRandomData.main(Main.scala)
```

Comment: Can you try with GeoMesa version 2.1 real quick?

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't using an underlying GeoMesa store to load data into a spark session you'll need to explicitly register the JTS types with:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.SQLTypes.init(spark.sqlContext)
```

This will register the `ST_` operations as well as the JTS encoders.

Answer (score 1):

In plain english, the exception is saying:

> I don't known how to convert a Point to a Spark type.

If you keep the latitude and longitude as doubles in your Dataset then you should be fine but as soon as you use an object like Point then you'll need to tell Spark how to convert it. In Spark terms, these are called Encoders and you can create custom ones.

Or you switch to an RDD where no conversion is necessary as long as you don't mind losing Spark SQL stuff.

Comment: That worked now! :).  I don't care at all about Spark SQL - I should have just smacked myself since I should just not deal with Dataframes, but instead deal with RDDs.